# How to activate user location sharing once user has declined location sharing using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display the native browser popup for location sharing even after user denying the location sharing.

consider the scenario,

user clicks location sharing button, native browser popup is shown. he allows to share his location the location button turns to green.

if the user declines sharing location, location button should be grey. and clicking that button should show a native browser popup...

with the code below, I am able to display a native popup browser again if I clear the site data from developertools->application->clear site data.

is it possible to show the native browser popup with clearing site data or so?

below is the code,

```
class Location extends react.purecomponent {
    state = {
        active: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
       if (navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.permissions.query({name: 
           'geolocation'}).then((result) => 
            {
               if (result.state === 'granted') {
                   this.setState({active: true});
               } else if (result.state === 'denied') {
                   this.setState({active: false});
               }
            });
        }
     }

     handle_location_btn_click = () => {
         if (navigator.geolocation) {

             navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'})
             .then((result) => {
                 if (result.state === 'granted') {
                     this.setState({active: true});
                 } else if (result.state === 'prompt') {
                     navigator.geolocation
                    .getCurrentPosition(this.use_position, null);
                 } else if (result.state === 'denied') {
                     this.setState({location_active: false});
                 }
            });
         } else {
            console.log("geolocation unavailable");
         }
     };

     render = () => {       
         return (
             <button type="button" className={this.active ? ' active': 
             '')} 
             onClick={this.handle_location_btn_click}>
             </button>
         );
      };
  }
```

Could someone help me with this.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible once the user said no to a location on specific domain